# Нужно вывести определенные данные из базы sqlite3 в кликабельные кнопки ReplyKeyboardMarkup

Tags: python, база-данных, бот, aiogram, sqlite3

Разрабатываю чат-бота в телеграм при помощи aiogram, новичок. У меня есть база данных sqlite3, в ней хранятся фио юзеров, их регионы, учебные заведения и другая информация.

Мне нужно сделать клавиатуру ReplyKeyboardMarkup, чтобы каждая кнопка отвечала за определенный регион из базы данных. Причем количество регионов неизвестно и может меняться, по нажатии на кнопку региона должны выводиться в другой клавиатуре учебные заведения юзеров выбранного региона. Проблема в том, что я даже примерно не представляю, как это можно реализовать.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно сделать хотя бы клавиатуру всех юзерских регионов из базы (дальше я разберусь, надеюсь), сойдет даже примерное описание методов, которые стоит использовать. Буду очень рад, если напишете код! Спасибо!

Comment: Для начала научитесь юзать sqlite, ибо если бы вы умели такой вопрос бы сформулировали по-другому. Всё ведь просто, вытаскиваете из бд данные, обрабатываете их и делаете клавиатуру.

Comment: То бишь вы вытаскиваете всё регионы из бд, оставляете только уникальные и делаете из этих строк клавиатуру

Comment: Подскажите инструмент, которым можно оставить только уникальные значения, пожалуйста

Comment: К примеру, Множества?

Comment: @oleksandrigo , изучив проблему, хочу переформулировать вопрос. Как создать уникальное имя для каждой кнопки, если кнопок неизвестное количество? Собрал названия регионов в список.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

but_list - список ваших значений

```
markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
for i in but_list:
    markup.add(f"P{i}")

# вместо P можно юзать какой-нибудь символ
@dp.message_handler(text_startswith="P")
async def button_pressed(msg: types.Message):
    button = msg.text[1:]
```